# Wer bin ich? (was: Another who am I riddle)

Tags: riddle, music

To add to the recent spate (should there be a who-am-i tag?):

I come from a brook.
I'm first in a book.
I'm old, but not stale.
From me was made hail.
I sound like an ocean,
perpetual motion.
I'm not quite a kernel,
nor am I nocturnal.

Who am I?

Hint: I have modified the title and added the [music](/questions/tagged/music) tag.

Comment: Nice riddle. It'd be better if you can come up with a clever and more informative title (preferably containing a subtle clue), instead of a generic title like "Another who am I riddle" (unless you cleverly managed to hide a clue in that...).

Comment: @BigBlackBox I have not cleverly managed to hide a clue in the title, but it seems I need to add a clue, so I will try to think of one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Prelude in C by J. S. Bach (BWV 846)

I come from a brook.

> J. S. Bach (Bach in german [title clue] means brook)

I'm first in a book.

> The first piece in "The Well-Tempered Clavier"

I'm old, but not stale.

> An old and good piece of music.

From me was made hail.

> Ave Maria was written to the tune... Hail Mary.

I sound like an ocean,

> Prelude in "sea" (thanks @hvd)

perpetual motion.

> The prelude itself has "perpetual motion" - steady pace of melody. Fugue (which belongs with this piece) means escape.

I'm not quite a kernel,

> Not a colonel... but a major. C major.

nor am I nocturnal.

> Not a nocturne?

Comment: Nice. Your interpretation of the perpetual motion clue also ties in to the OP's user name.

Comment: I have an idea about one of the clues you don't have, if you'd like (never mind, you got it)

Comment: Very good, definitely on the right track, but not exactly correct.

Comment: Ok, everything you've posted is correct (except I wasn't thinking of the fugue at all, so there's some unanticipated material under "perpetual motion."  I'm going to withhold the accept until you get the "not quite a kernel" clue, however.  Also, the WTC comprises two books (the clue was originally "I'm in the first book").

Comment: Ooh, not right on the "kernel" line.  Here's a hint.  After I posted, I realized that the lines in the third couplet should have been reversed: `Perpetual motion: / I sound like an ocean.`.

Comment: Better? A bit of a language barrier, my first association is always the [latin for hard], not [not quite kernel].

Comment: @orion Congratulations.  Latin for "big" -- both intervals and ranks.

Answer (score 3):

You are

> a **tree**.

I come from a brook.

> Water is on of main life sources of trees, and brook is a source of water.

I'm first in a book.

> A book was a tree at first, while it's produced from lumber. So tree is first step of a book in its history.

I'm old, but not stale.

> Trees replenish themselves every year (at springs), even if they are very old.

From me was made hail.

> Trees improve possibilty to rain.

I sound like an ocean,

> If wind blows, trembling leaves of trees sound like ocean.

perpetual motion.

> A tree dies every winter, replenishes every spring. Every year, until it cut down by a human.

I'm not quite a kernel,

> Trees multiply via and grow from kernels, by they are not kernels when they grow.

nor am I nocturnal.

> Trees can't make photosynthesis at night. They are more active at days.

Comment: Ah, this is a nice answer, but it is not what I had in mind.  I will add a clue shortly.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is:

> Water.
>
>  It comes from a brook, water is in the water cycle so it's old but not stale. Hail comes from water. Oceans are made of water so it will sound like Oceans. Water is in perpetual motion.

Comment: this came to my mind too. I even wrote the answer. But when I came to the last sentence I realised that I was wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid you have fallen for the misdirection.  The answer is not water.  I will add a hint shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Ok at first I thought water but they realised that was wrong, so I have come up with a new answer:

> You're a cloud

I come from a brook.

> Clouds are made of water, (well water vapour)

I'm first in a book.

> Not sure, maybe something to do with being white? White page, white cloud?

I'm old but not stale.

> Not sure again, but I suppose there has always been clouds so that makes them old.

From me was made hail.

> Well hail comes out of clouds were they are made

I sound like an ocean.

> Storm cloud (Thunder sounding like waves) or something to do with rain

Perpetual motion.

> I suppose clouds are always on the move

I'm not quite a kernel,

> not sure, maybe the sun is the kernel and clouds merely part of the scenery?

nor am I nocturnal.

> You can't see clouds at night.

Am I right?

Comment: Nice reasoning, but incorrect, I'm afraid.  I will add a hint shortly.

Comment: JoeBeastlyGerbil, welcome to the site! It is customary to hide our guesses using the "spoiler" formatting. For that, use `>!` when starting the line instead of a simple `>`.

Comment: Oh thanks I'd seen people do it but never known how...